# Linq to Entities Querying for Nullable data types

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I got a scenario where we are doing soft delete on the rows in database. I want to include the rows that are not deleted. How can I achieve it using LINQ.

Say

```
from c in context.ASDSet
where (c => c.DeletedFlag.HasValue && !c.DeletedFlag.Value)
```

But I couldn't achieve the result.

I want the resultant SQL to be of form:

```
select *  from table where IsNull(column, 0) = 0
```

Comment: What was the result set value for DeletedFlag? Is it emitting as '0' or '1' or true/false ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you *actually* want:

```
var query = Context.ASDSet.Where(c => c.DeletedFlag == null || 
                                      c.DeletedFlag.Value == false);
```

In other words, that *includes* rows where the flag is null, whereas your current query *excludes* rows where the flag is null.